# NSDateComponentsFormatter output differer between builds

Tags: swift, macos, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I have this piece of code that shows an about window with a time interval in seconds that is supposed to be formatted to minutes or hours. It works fine when I build and test locally but the version on the Mac App Store only shows the time in seconds. Any clue why this is?

```
// Seconds between UI update
var updateInterval = 300.0 {
        didSet {
            log("Update interval changed to \(updateInterval)")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setDouble(updateInterval, forKey: settingsKey)
            startTimer()
        }
    }

@IBAction func showAbout(sender: NSMenuItem) {
        let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
        formatter.unitsStyle = .Full
        formatter.allowedUnits = [.Minute, .Hour]
        //formatter.calendar = nil // Disable localization

        // Use the configured formatter to generate the string.
        let updateIntervalTimeString = formatter.stringFromTimeInterval(updateInterval)

        let alert = NSAlert()
        alert.addButtonWithTitle(NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Ok button on about screen"))

        alert.messageText = NSLocalizedString("ABOUT", comment: "About screen")

        let infoString =
            NSLocalizedString("ABOUT_INFO_1", comment: "App name") + "\n\n" +
            NSLocalizedString("ABOUT_INFO_2", comment: "Update interval info") +
                "\(updateIntervalTimeString!)" + "\n\n" +
            NSLocalizedString("ABOUT_INFO_3", comment: "Copyright notice")
        alert.informativeText = infoString


        alert.alertStyle = NSAlertStyle.InformationalAlertStyle

        alert.runModal()
    }
```

Comment: How is `updateInterval` populated?

Comment: updateInterval is a double, added the declaration

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that the behavior was different if I start the app from the App Store, Spotlight or Launchpad. So I deleted all binaries and downloaded the app again from the store and now the time is displayed correctly.